# Smooth scrolling effect for > Height (parallax effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for parallax effect. Like this [scroll effect](http://revox.io/frontend/index.html).

All I got is this

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
            $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```

I want a more smooth effect, when I'm > 80px, like the scroll effect mentioned.

Comment: sidenote: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method

Comment: im using  query-1.12.4, but would it be best to upgrade?

Comment: @Homme Don't upgrade. Many of them don't work.

Comment: only upgrade if you wouldn't waste hours redoing your code or if you need something that is in a newer version, a lot has changed since 1.12.4.

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but how could i modify this make it more smooth?

Comment: explain `I want a more smooth effect`.

Comment: Okay... If you tried using my link, you will see the effect i'm looking is more a sliding efftect. > 80px i want the menubar / container comming sliding in from the top.

Comment: @Homme I have answered for you. Kindly check. I have used the same jQuery version as you have.

Comment: @Homme Ask me if you have any questions on the transitions I have used. Glad that it helped you.

Comment: @Kumar Thanks, but why are you showing a different menu?

Comment: @Homme Yes, the example you showed me had two different menus.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done a similar prototype using CSS Transitions and jQuery for a better smooth effect. Kindly check this out. CSS transitions are carried out by GPU, while jQuery transitions are made using CPU and mathematical calculations. So definitely it would look sluggish.

Also, I have used the same jQuery version (more or less) so that you don't need to mess up with the versions. `:)`

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20)
      $(".scrolled").addClass("show");
    else
      $(".scrolled").removeClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; line-height: 1;}

body {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}

header {line-height: 5; text-align: center; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear; -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear; -o-transition: all 0.25s linear; transition: all 0.25s linear;}
header.scrolled {line-height: 3; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc; background-color: #fff; height: 0; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999;}
header.scrolled.show {height: 3em;}

.first {background-color: #ccf; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1300px; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<header class="scrolled">
  Scrolled Header
</header>
<div class="first">
  <header class="normal">
    Normal Header
  </header>
</div>
```